# Ubuntu 18.04 Server UEFI Enable Plymouth

Tags: 18.04, uefi, plymouth

So I "converted" Bionic Server UEFI to Mate Desktop UEFI.

One thing that bugs me though is that I cannot seem to enable plymouth.

this is what alternatives is set to:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative default.plymouth (providing /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth).

  Selection    Path                                                                           Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-mate-logo/ubuntu-mate-logo.plymouth           150       auto mode
  1            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-mate-logo/ubuntu-mate-logo-scale-2.plymouth   149       manual mode
  2            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-mate-logo/ubuntu-mate-logo.plymouth           150       manual mode
```

This is what */etc/default/grub* is set to:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_GFXMODE=2048x1080
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD=keep
```

This file exists:

```
-rw-r--r-- /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-mate-logo/ubuntu-mate-logo.plymouth
```

Results:

Text output at boot.

Comment: Does `/usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-mate-logo/ubuntu-mate-logo.plymouth` exist? Also check the permissions, I think it should be executable.

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED:

```
sudo apt purge grub-pc
sudo apt install --reinstall grub-efi-amd64
```

Added: *"quiet splash"* to *GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX* in */etc/default/grub*

```
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```